# DROP DATABASE cannot run inside a transaction block

Tags: python-3.x, database, postgresql, psycopg2

when I run this code:

```
cur, conn = create_database()
```

I get an error:

```
ActiveSqlTransaction                      Traceback (most recent call last)
x:\Users\user\xxxxx\xxxx.ipynb Cell 19 line 1
----> 1 cur, conn = create_database()

x:\Users\user\xxxxx\xxxx.ipynb Cell 19 line 5
     2 conn = psycopg2.connect("host=localhost dbname=postgres user=postgres password=****")
      3 cur = conn.cursor()
----> 5 cur.execute("DROP DATABASE accounts")
      6 cur.execute("CREATE DATABASE accounts")
      8 conn.set_session(autocommit=True)

ActiveSqlTransaction: DROP DATABASE cannot run inside a transaction block
```

i have created a create_database function in a different cell.
Here is the function:

```
def create_database():
    conn = psycopg2.connect("host=localhost dbname=postgres user=postgres password=********")
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute("DROP DATABASE accounts")
    cur.execute("CREATE DATABASE accounts")

    conn.set_session(autocommit=True)

    cur.close()
    conn.close()

    conn = psycopg2.connect("host=localhost dbname=accounts user=postgres password=********")
    cur = conn.cursor()

    return cur, conn
```

What is the meaning of the ActiveSqlTransactionError?

i've tried commenting out the DROP DATABASE line but I still get the same error for CREATE DATABASE.

Comment: In PostgreSQL, certain statements like CREATE DATABASE and DROP DATABASE are not allowed within a transaction because they are administrative commands that affect the entire database cluster.

Comment: You should probably move `conn.set_session(autocommit=True)` to before the drop command